# Force overwrite of a file macOS

Tags: ios

wondering if someone could help me with an issue I have run into, which I believe is related to how a Mac handles an instruction to overwrite a file of the same name. I am using an audio software programme (Pure Data) on my Mac which is sending a command to write a file to the hard drive every x seconds. The first time I specify a file path / name to write to, the file is correctly written to the folder at the specified location. However, when the command is sent x seconds later to write another file of the same name to the same location, the file does not overwrite the existing file of the same name. (Interestingly if I look at the time modified column it says it has updated to the time the new file was written, however, the contents of the file are not overwritten).

I have tried the same programme on a PC and it works as intended (i.e. the file is automatically overwritten with the new audio recording).

I know I could create new files with new names, but for the purposes of what I'm doing, that will make life extremely complicated. What I want to do is just to automatically overwrite this one file every time I send the command to write to the file path.

I suspect the problem is due protections in Mac to stop overwriting files without a prompt to agree to it, if that makes sense? What I'd like to know is how to override this for just this one file so that when the command is sent from the audio programme the file is automatically overwritten with the latest contents.

Best
Jess

Comment: Try running `chown $USER FILE_PATH` on the file.

Comment: This depends on what API is used under the hood. A workaround is to delete a previous file before writing it out.